# Ruby On Rails, SQL and SQL parameters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, parameters, sql-injection

I have complex SQL query. I need safely to pass parameters to SQL query. How can I avoid sql injections without using activerecord? Where should I keep SQL models/controllers? Does anyone know good practice to work with SQL server without activerecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bypass ActiveRecord you pretty much have to do everything manually.  I assume you have good reasons for doing so.

[ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) has the following methods: sanitize_sql_for_assignments (for set) and sanitize_sql_for_conditions (for select).  There are a few other sanitize_sql_* that are probably worth looking at too.  Both accept a hash (uses the keys as column names) or a string.

I could be mistaken, but to fetch records and skip ActiveRecord, I think you use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) which should return objects from your database connector.  Checks the docs for the connector to see what is returned and how to work with it.

As for best practices, sorry, I can't help you there :-)

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has `sanitize_sql` functions for this.
You can check the [source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-saanitize_sql_array) of this methods.